# Does xpath support "or" function

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

In case below two elements do not show in same time

```
<a title='a' />
<b title='b' />
```

I want to check if one of them can show

does xpath support the 'or' function? I just want to write in one line:

`//a[@title='a'] or .. @title='b'` ??

Answer (score 1):

[XPath Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp)

Select either matching nodes (your case here):

```
//a[@title='a'] | //b[@title='b']
```

Select one element with either matching attributes

```
//a[@title='a' or @title='b']
```

Comment: The second example can also be written `//a[@title=('a', 'b')]` - XPath 2.0 only.

Comment: @Tingting: Do you have any feedback on this? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match either `<a/>` elements with `@title='a'` attribute *or* `<b/>` elements with `@title='b'` attribute, you can also match all elements and perform a test on their name:

```
//*[local-name(.) = 'a' and @title='a' or local-name(.) = 'b' and @title='b']
```